# Smart way of solving marshalling datatypes from library to C++ primatives

Tags: c++, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm using a library (don't have access to the sources) which has it's own data types, e.g. library::object::library_string, library::object::library_number. There is a enum stored alongside the type which tells you about the type (i.e. library::object::type)

The library provides methods on the library::object like isString(), isNumber() to query the type. The library also provides getString(), getNumber() which throw an exception if they are called on the wrong type.

I'm using the library from my application and I want to populate my C++ primitives with as little tedious code as possible. One issue is that because the library::object could be null or an unexpected type, I should check for the type using isXXXX() then use getXXXX() to populated my C++ model.

To prevent lots of code like myModel.myPrimativeVariable = isXXXX() ? getXXXX() : *null_condition_type_for_this_type like "" or 0*

What's the best was to achieve this? It's a shame the library didn't provide a tryGetValue() method.

I could write a bunch of functions each type (different signatures) so I can do:

myModel->myInt = getIntValue(objectInstance)
myModel->myString = getStringValue(objectInstance)

where objectInstance is a library::object instance

or I could use templates and have one function which tries to cast the type to the template type.

I've encountered this 'problem' before and normally opt to write wrappers, but it feels naive. I feel this must be a 'solved' problem. I like to think there are better ways?

Thanks